# How to receive POST data in Django, Should use django forms or Django REST framework?

Tags: django

I'm not familliar with django. I don't know the differences between django forms and Django REST framework.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't provide enough information to give a meaningful answer.  If you're a django novice, use the built-in forms until you have a good reason not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Django REST Framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/) is a framework for creating REST APIs. [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) is a utility in Django that makes it easy to create a form on your website and validate the input.

Both can use POST data. A normal view can receive POST data just as well `request.POST` is a dictionary with all the keys and values send via POST. 
The added benefit of Django forms or Django REST Framework is that it can automate what you wish to do with the POST data.

That being said Django REST Framework is used mostly to create APIs for other applications to use, e.g. a mobile app, a webservice etc. 
Django forms is what you would use if, for instance, you're making a forum, comment, or Contact me page.

Which one you'd use depends entirely on what you're making. Also, in my opinion, Django REST Framework is harder to work with than the normal forms for many tasks. So if you're learning it start with Django forms.

Too answer the first question in your title, 'How to receive POST data in Django' the following example should suffice:

```
def contactview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        msg = request.POST.get('message')
        sender = request.POST.get('email')
        send_email('contact@example.com', msg=msg, reply_to=sender)
        return render(request, 'contactsend.html')
    return render(request, 'contactform.html')
```

There might be an small error in the example somewhere it's written from memory so keep that in mind that this is not exactly copy+paste and it works code.